# Installing a private key via SyncML on Windows

Tags: windows, mdm

Has anyone succeeded in installing a client certificate + private key from an MDM application onto a Windows device?

I'm referencing the [ClientCertificateInstall configuration service provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/mdm/clientcertificateinstall-csp#devicepfxcertinstalluniqueidkeylocation) to build [this SyncML document](https://pastebin.com/sJV9hghe) for the Windows client. When the windows client reports back to the MDM application, it gives [this SyncML document](https://pastebin.com/B8XYtGYL) which reveals a problem with the `KeyLocation` node.

The `KeyLocation` status is simply `500`, which isn't very informative, but the statuses in other parts of the client's report show that all other parts of my command should succeed.

Experiment details:

- In the linked example, I specify a `KeyLocation` of `2`: `Install to TPM if present. If not present, fallback to software.` But I've also experimented with `1` and `3` with identical results.
- For a Windows client, I've used a VM on Hyper-V with TPM support and a VM on VirtualBox (no TPM support).
- In addition to `./Device/Vendor/MSFT/ClientCertificateInstall/PFXCertInstall`, I've also tried `./User/Vendor/MSFT/ClientCertificateInstall/PFXCertInstall`.